# Eclipse takes a long time to index Javascript files

Tags: javascript, eclipse

My Eclipse often takes a long time (up to half an hour) to index Javascript files in my maven project, it freezes the workspace and I cant do anything but wait for it to finish.

[image]

What does the "Indexing" do? How can I make it fast?
Thanks

Comment: Do you need JavaScript indexing ? Are you editing the JavaScript files in Eclipse ?

Comment: No i dont need javascript indexing. yes im editing javacript files in eclipse and everytime i do changes and save, it triggers the indexing

Comment: my apologies for the previous statement. I need to index javascript at my source code folder, but definitely not those at the "target" folder, which its taking forever to index. How do i exclude the "target" folder from indexing?

Comment: I think I got it. Excluding the "target" from the project did the trick

Comment: You should answer your own question then.

Comment: With a screenshot of where in the UI you changed things.

Comment: eclipse does nothing with that indexing.. javascript we get absolutely no user experience on eclispe.. disable it completely..also disable validations